# ('can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str',) on mysql.connector.connect in Python

Tags: python, mysql, database-connection, pymysql

I have a problem in Python. The system says `("'tuple' object has no attribute 'strip'",)` above the function `cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host=self.host, database=self.database , user= self.username , password=self.password )`, as if it were recognizing the comma as a concatenation. I spent hours and I can't solve it.

```
class Database:
    def __init__(
        self,
        host="localhost",
        database="bayer",
        username="root",
        password="root",
        port="3306",
    ) -> None:
        self.host = str(host)
        self.database = str(database)
        self.username = str(username)
        self.password = str(password)
        self.port =str(port)
        self.connection = None
    
    
    def connectDatabase(self):
        try:
            logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
            
            if self.connection is not None:
                logging.info("return active connection for you")
                return self.connection
                       
            self.connection =  mysql.connector.connect(host=self.host, database=self.database , user=self.username , password=self.password )
            
            
            logging.info("CON02")
            
            if self.connection.is_connected():
                logging.info("You're connected to database: " + self.database)
                return self.connection
            else:
                logging.error(
                    "Error in connected to database: " +
                    self.database)
            logging.info("CON03")
        except Error as e:
            logging.info("Database Error: " + e.args)
            #raise (e)

    def query(self, connection, sql, *args):
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        try:
            cursor.execute(sql, args)
            return cursor
        except Error as e:
            logging.error("Database Error: " + e.args)
            raise (e)
```

I just need to get past this line with the connection made.

Comment: do i understand you correct that the error happens when you try to connect? not when executing a query? can you print the connection arguments right before connecting and give us the output?

Comment: Let's see the full stack trace and also how you're constructing your Database class

Comment: There is no occurrence of `strip` is your code, please share the full stack trace so that we can see what code is actually producing that error.

Answer (score 1):

`e.args` is a tuple, i.e

```
>>> type(ValueError().args)
<class 'tuple'>
```

So, when trying to concatenate a string with a tuple, i.e `logging.info("Database Error: " + e.args)` it crashes:

```
>>> "" + ()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str
```

You could join on the `e.args` to concatenate them without an error being raised:

```
logging.info("Database Error: " + "".join(e.args))
```

or, event better, use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals)

```
logging.info(f"Database Error: {e.args}")
```